# Error when trying to distribute via pip

Tags: python, pip

I uploaded my package on pypi using [this guide](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html).

But it seems that there is an error with this line in setup.py

```
long-description=open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'README.md')).read()
```

which is giving me, on trying to install via pip

```
IO Error no such file or directory.
```

So how can I fix this? should a simple open('README.md')?

Is the long-description line really needed when I already have this in my setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
description-file = README.md
```

Comment: You're presumably missing an `os.path.join()` call around the dirname and `'README.md'`.

Comment: @senshin sorry, I am not missing that. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @senshin I can confirm it works locally using setup.py, but when I tried to install it in a new virtualenv via pip it fails. The directory its looking into is `working-directory/venv/build/pkgname/README.md`

Comment: setup.py is run on the target machine after the downloaded distribution is expanded. Have you included README.md in the distribution?

Comment: @tdelaney yes the README.md is there and it works fine via setup.py install

Comment: Same exact problem... It seems to go away if I copy paste the README content into a variable in setup.py and refer long-description to it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'include README.md' in `MANIFEST.in`, if you do not have this file (the Manifest one), create it.

Just execute this on your repository root directory (where the setup.py file is located)

```
echo "include README.md" >> MANIFEST.in
```

Cheers.